# regex from json array in JMeter

Tags: json, regex, jmeter

I need to extract start and end dates from a long json array which looks similar to this :

```
:   {
:   :   "id":10069,
:   :   "type":"Programming",
:   :   "preprID":25053483,
:   :   "contentfulId":"5StbNjpoGsyMqw2a6M4iwI",
:   :   "title":"Bas",
:   :   "start":"2017-09-14T03:00:00+02:00",
:   :   "end":"2017-09-14T06:00:00+02:00",
:   :   "description":"Blabla",
:   :   "showOnlineAvailable":true,
:   :   "allowMetadata":true,

:   },
:   {
:   :   "id":10070,
:   :   "type":"Programming",
:   :   "preprID":9249755,
:   :   "contentfulId":"4VoOfJbuIoA6qq6eyQukcM",
:   :   "title":"Someone",
:   :   "start":"2017-09-14T06:00:00+02:00",
:   :   "end":"2017-09-14T10:00:00+02:00",
:   :   "description":"Blabla.",
:   :   "showOnlineAvailable":true,
:   :   "allowMetadata":true,
```

How can I extract the start and the related end date at once?
The start/end dates will be called randomly for all concurrent users, so I need to make sure the dates both match accordingly.

So in short, each concurrent user in my jmeter test will extract a random start/end date and these will be used in further requests.

I tried using `"start":"([^"]+)"|"end":"([^"]+)"` but JMeter doesnt seem to get the second group.

Comment: You just want to fetch start and end dates from this array?

Comment: yes, the array is much longer. but each time i want to randomly extract a START + END date.

Comment: What have u tried so far?

Comment: "start":"([^"]+)"|"end":"([^"]+)"



altough the second group (end) doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 0):

```
(?s)"start":"(.*?)",*"end":"(.*?)",
```

did the trick. both groups now are captured using $1$$2$

Answer (score 0):

You can get both regular expression using Template: `$1$$2$`. see [regex jmeter manual](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html), But I think you need 2 seperate variables so I 'm suggesting:

Use 2 post porcessor regular expression one with "start":"([^"]+) and the second with: end":"([^"]+)"  ,each with different reference name

For random value put 0 in Match No. (0 for Random)

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be Regex? - I've not used it but you may want to look at [JSON Extractor Post Processor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter), as it's JSON data.

I presume (but haven't tested) that you can use something like

```
$.[${randomNum}].start
```

to reference the array item directly.

As per other answer you may need two Post Processers (one per data field) to extract both values.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and configure it as follows:

   - Variable names: any 2 variable names separated by semicolon, i.e. `start; end`
   - JSON Path Expresions: `$..start; $..end`
   - Match No: `-1`
   - Default Values: `NOT FOUND; NOT FOUND`

     [image: JMeter JSON Path Expressions]

     Once you execute your request it will generate the following JMeter Variables:

     ```
             end_1=2017-09-14T06:00:00+02:00
             end_2=2017-09-14T10:00:00+02:00
             end_matchNr=2
             start_1=2017-09-14T03:00:00+02:00
             start_2=2017-09-14T06:00:00+02:00
             start_matchNr=2
     ```
2. If you need to use a random variable later on you can use expressions assuming [__V()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V) and [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) functions combinations like:

   - for `start` variables: `${__V(start_${__Random(1,${start_matchNr},)})}`
   - for `end` variables: `${__V(end_${__Random(1,${end_matchNr},)})}`

     See [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables) for more information.